# Custom Connect signal is not working in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am using connect signal in QT, I'm getting below errors when I'm running the application on our device,

```
QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::display_frame()
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

error in runtime Application.

Below is my code,

```
Mainwindow.h

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H

#define MAINWINDOW_H

//qt includes
#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QGraphicsView>

#include <QTimer>

#include <QTime>

#include "iris_test.h"

extern int disp_status;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void display_frame();
signals:
    void request_iris_capture();   
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


Mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QByteArray>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(ui->graphicsView);
    intervalTimer = new QTimer(this);
    clock = new QTimer(this);

    irisThread = new QThread();
    Ir_Test = new Iris_Test();

    Ir_Test->moveToThread(irisThread);
    irisThread->start();
    connect(this, SIGNAL(request_iris_capture()), Ir_Test, SLOT(Request_Stream()));
    connect(Ir_Test, SIGNAL(display_irisdata()), this, SLOT(display_frame()));

    emit request_iris_capture();
}

void MainWindow::display_frame()
{
  qDebug() << "display frame function called" << endl;
}


iris_test.h

#ifndef IRIS_TEST_H
#define IRIS_TEST_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>

class Iris_Test: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Iris_Test(QObject *parent = 0);
    int Streaming_init();

public slots:
    void Request_Stream();

signals:
    void display_irisdata();
};

#endif // IRIS_TEST_H

iris_test.cpp

#include "iris_test.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTime>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <ui_mainwindow.h>


Iris_Test::Iris_Test(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{         
}

void Iris_Test::Request_Stream()
{
 emit display_irisdata();
}
```

FYI,

1. Sending a request_iris_capture signal from Mainwindow to Request_Stream() - Request_Stream function is getting called
2. Request_Stream() will send a signal to display_frame() function - This is not happening

Comment: add `public slots:` before `void display_frame();`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are missing a `slots` keyword in your header file. Without it [moc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html) will not register that method in meta-object system.

The definition of the `display_frame()` should be as follows:

```cpp
public slots:
    void display_frame();
```

---

However, if you can't use the moc keywords (`signals`, `slots`, and `emit`), because these names will be used by a third-party library or your code, you can avoid them as described in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#using-qt-with-3rd-party-signals-and-slots).